# For loop not removing views?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have the following code:

```
    for (NSImageView *image in self.view.subviews) {
        if (image.frame.size.height == 67 && image.frame.size.width == 46) {
            [image removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

This is called when a button is pressed. I want each NSImageView that has those dimensions to be removed. The problem is, it removes one only. I have to keep clicking the button over and over to clear the images. There is 4 of them.

However, I noticed that the log it produces shows the very last line getting removed each time. I'm guessing because these images are the top-most layers.

So my question is, how can I make it so each NSImageViews with a height of 67 and width of 46 are removed from the view at once?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you not getting an error message about mutating an array while enumerating? What is self.view?

Comment: Yes I am getting that message. The view is the view where the images are in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mutating array error should prevent your code from executing. Use this instead:

```
NSArray *copy = [self.views.subviews copy];

for (NSImageView *image in copy) {
    if (image.frame.size.height == 67 && image.frame.size.width == 46) {
        [image removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```